# Bottom Nav Android Jetpack Compose issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomnav

The below is an overview of the BottomNav implementation.The app shows the bottom Nav bar properly but when an item is selected, it calls the NavHost multiple times. I see a similar issue for Jetpack compose samples https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetsnack. Is there any workaround to avoid multiple Navhost calls?

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomMenu(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        BottomNavGraphBar(navController = navController)
    }
}

// handling the click event

  BottomNavigationItem(
        
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)
                launchSingleTop = true
            }
        }
    )

//NavHost implementation
@Composable
fun BottomNavGraphBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
            Log.d("BottomNavGraph","BottomNavGraph->HomeScreen")
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Settings.route) {
            Log.d("BottomNavGraph","BottomNavGraph->AppSettingsScreen")
            AppSettingsScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Profile.route) {
            Log.d("BottomNavGraph","BottomNavGraph->ProfileScreen")
            ProfileScreen()
        }
    }
}

<!---LogCat-->
// When app is launched
BottomNavGraph->HomeScreen
BottomNavGraph->HomeScreen
// clicked on the profile.
BottomNavGraph->HomeScreen
BottomNavGraph->ProfileScreen
BottomNavGraph->HomeScreen
BottomNavGraph->ProfileScreen
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Recomposition can happen multiple times in a row, up to once a frame, during animation. And this is exactly what's happening in this case - transition between two routes: the old route is fading away and the new one is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Compose can (and will, depending on multiple things) call composable functions to "re-compose" them. Although it is smart and can *cache* the output of composable functions for their previous inputs, so that it does not have to recompute their results (e.g. their emitted UI).

In your example, the `composable(..) { ... }` might get recomposed, but if you use composables inside it (like a few `Text`s) it will use its cache from its last rendering.

You don't need to worry about your functions being called, but you do have to take care of your computations. This is why you'd want to use [remember](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) to calculate something and store it in the cache, so it is not re-calculated again.